# How to fix gcc not found error in a make file, although having it installed and functioning normally?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, assembly, gnu-make

I'm trying to compile and link an assembly and c program, using GCC and GNU Make, but when I run the "make" command it throws an error "couldn't find GCC", even though I have it installed and working correctly, after some fixing the make file now throws an couldn't find make command in line 14!!!

I've already tried to compile it in another machine but it didn't work. And of course I've tried to run regular GCC commands and it worked perfectly! All seems alright with environment variables. If I try to run the commands without make, it throws a linker.ld syntax error, but that I'm assuming it's on me.

Make file:

```
CC=gcc 
TARGET=bookOs
C_FILES=./kernel.c
OBJS=$(C_FILES:.c=.o) 

all compile: $(TARGET) 
all: finale 
.PHONY: all compile clean finale 

%.o: 
    gcc -c $(@:.o=.c) -ffreestanding -fno-exceptions -m32 

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    ​$(shell nasm -f elf start.asm -o start.o)
    ​gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -lgcc start.o  $? -T linker.ld -o $(TARGET)

finale: 
    ​$(shell cd ~/Desktop/bookOs/) ​
    $(shell cp $(TARGET) ./iso/boot/$(TARGET))
    $(shell grub2-mkrescue iso --output=$(TARGET).iso) 

clean: 
    ​rm -f *.o $(TARGET) $(TARGET).iso 
    ​find . -name \*.o | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

Assembly file:

```
bits 32
global _start 
extern kernel_early
extern main

section .text 
    align 4
    dd 0x1BADB002   ;magic
    dd 0x00
    dd - (0x1BADB002 + 0x00)    ;checksum
_start: 
    cli 
    mov esp, stack
    call kernel_early
    call main
    hlt

section .bss
resb 8192

stack:
```

C File:

```c
static char* const VGA_MEMORY = (char*)0xb8000;

static const int VGA_WIDTH = 80;

static const int VGA_HEIGHT = 25;

void kernel_early(void) 
{  }

int main(void) {
    const char *str = "Hello world"; unsigned int i = 0;
    string position unsigned int j = 0; // place holder for video buffer position 

    ​while (str[i] != '\0') { ​
        VGA_MEMORY[j] = str[i];
        ​VGA_MEMORY[j + 1] = 0x07; 
        ​i++; ​j = j + 2; 
    ​} ​

    return 0; 

}
```

Link file:

```
SECTIONS 
{ 
    . = 0x100000; 
    .text : { *(.text) } 
    .bss  : { *(.bss)  } 
}
```

**This is the error it is currently throwing:**

```
make: ​: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:14: bookOs] Error 127
```

I expect that this make file generated an output linking the c file and the assembly file. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just remove that `$(shell ...)` nonsense everywhere and see if it got fixed

Answer (score 5):

The commands starting with `$(shell` are not doing what you might expect. Please read `make`'s documentation:

> [...] it takes as an argument a shell command and evaluates to the output of the
>   command.

Everything after `shell` is run as a shell command AND THEN the output of this command is interpreted by `make` as if it was literally in the Makefile. In your case this will be a command. One example from the documentation:

> files := $(shell echo *.c)

So the solution is to remove `$(shell` and the closing parenthesis.

*Hint: To see what `make` will do without actually doing it, call it with option `-n`.*